# How to use OData in ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I try to use OData in an ASP. Bellow my code:

```
//============== Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddDbContext<EntriesContext>(
        opt => opt.UseMySql("server=localhost;database=mydb;user=myusr;password=mypass",
        mysqlOptions =>{mysqlOptions.ServerVersion(new Version(5..), ServerType.MySql);}));

    services.AddOData();
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
        ...
        app.UseMvc(b => { b.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel()); });
    }

    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel() {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Entry>("Entries");
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

The Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[EnableCors("AllowMyOrigin")]
public class EntriesController : ODataController
{
    private readonly EntriesContext _context;

    public EntriesController(EntriesContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public ActionResult<List<Entry>> GetAll() {
        return _context.Entries.ToList();
    }
```

And the context:

```
public class EntriesContext : DbContext
{
    public EntriesContext(DbContextOptions<EntriesContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Entry> Entries { get; set; }
}
```

however, is not clear for me, what path should I use to get the entries (without OData I would use `localhost:9000/api/entries`, but now I am confused).

I tried to do `https://localhost:44384/odata/entries` and `https://localhost:44384/odata/api/entries` but I get 404

I tried to comment the controller's route, like this

```
//[Route("api/[controller]")]
//[ApiController]
[EnableCors("AllowMyOrigin")]
public class EntriesController : ODataController
```

and also modified the action

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
public IActionResult Get() {
    return Ok(_db.Entries);
}
```

I tried then `https://localhost:44384/odata/Entries` and gotthe full list of the entries... However, the `https://localhost:44384/odata/Entries?$take=2` does not work: 400 Bad Request: `Parameter name: $take' is not supported."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `[ApiController]` annotation when you inherit from `ODataController`. Remove the annotation and it should work as expected.
To be able to query using `$take` you need to setup it:

```
app.UseMvc(b =>
      {
        b.Take();
        b.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
      });
```

You can also add other actions, e.g. `Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(100).Count()`

Comment: I also remarked it does not work with `public ActionResult<List<Entry>> GetAll() {` but with `IActionResult Get()`

Comment: Now I get "Parameter name: $take' is not supported" when try to use skip or take (see my edit)

Comment: `Take` such method doesn't exist... I did `b.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(100).Count();`